# ActionScript - Difference Between "Wildcard" and Object Datatypes?

Tags: actionscript-3, object, wildcard

When declaring a variable to have an open datatype, is there any difference, especially a performance difference, between typing a variable as a "wildcard" (i'm not sure of the official name for this) and typing a variable as an Object?

```
var myVar:*;

var myVar:Object;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wont affect performance. I use * when I dont know which type the Object will be until runtime.

From livedocs: use * under these circumstances:

> - When you want to defer type checking to runtime. You can use an
>     untyped property or expression to
>     circumvent compile-time type checking
>     in strict mode. Note, however, that
>     runtime type checking of assignment
>     statements occurs whether you use
>     strict mode or not.
> - When you want to store the value undefined in a property. Unlike
>     previous versions of ActionScript, the
>     value undefined is not a member of the
>     Object data type. You must use an
>     untyped property to store the value
>     undefined.

Answer (score 1):

All variable and class types in ActionScript 3 are child classes of `Object`, so in terms of functionality, I don't think there is any difference between the two.

Some sub-classes of `Object` like `int` and `Number` behave like stack objects (this means that `var firstInt:int = 5` and `var secondInt:int = 5` actually point to the same `Object`), but that doesn't affect how they are treated when you point to them using a generic variable.

If I could hazard a guess, I'd say they added the wildcard as both a way to save typing and to make it easier for C/C++ migrants who are used to referencing generic types with a `void*` pointer rather than a base `Object` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both *types* in the same way. There are a few differences between them though. Wildcard types have an additional value: **undefined**.

```
var a: Object;
var b: *;
var c: *;

trace(a + ": " + getQualifiedClassName(a) + "       " + b + ": " + getQualifiedClassName(b) + "       " + c + ": " + getQualifiedClassName(c));

b = a;
a = c;

if (a == undefined)
    trace("compiles with a warning");
```